# jQuery this to show one element

Tags: jquery, this

I have the following jQuery

```
$('td a').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('div.productPopUp').show();
});
```

and this HTML

```
<td>text</td>
   <td><a href="#">text</a></td>
   <div class="productPopUp">
     <h1>text</h1>
     <p>blah, blah</p>                          
   </div>
<td>

<td>text</td>
     <td><a href="#">text</a></td>
     <div class="productPopUp">
        <h1>text</h1>
        <p>blah, blah</p>                           
     </div>
 <td>
```

I want the jQuery to show only the hovered link, but it does not work. I'm not sure if I am using this in the wrong place or wrong context. (I assumed this, used here referred to what is hovered over?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to fix your markup. You have extra opening `td` tags after each block, and you shouldn't be dropping `div` tags randomly into a table structure.

Comment: Before jumping to jQuery, fix a bit your HTML and CSS first. You're missing <tr> tags

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need some valid markup, jQuery can not always find elements in strange invalid markup?

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>text</td>
       <td><a href="#">text</a></td>
       <td class="productPopUp">
          <h1>text</h1>
          <p>blah, blah</p>                          
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>text</td>
         <td><a href="#">text</a></td>
         <td class="productPopUp">
           <h1>text</h1>
           <p>blah, blah</p>                           
         </td>
    </tr>
​</table>​​​​​​​​​​
```

Then some jQuery, something like this maybe:

```
$('td a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".productPopUp").toggle();
});
```

And lastly a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/vK7dq/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td a').hover(function(){
  $(this).parent().next('div.productPopUp').show();
});
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but it does not work. Thanks for the speedy reply though..!

Comment: I've removed the div from within the table structure. It was originally there as a quick and dirty test. The answers given still don't work however.

Comment: If you've removed it then what does the current markup look like? Are the `h1` and `p` just inline with the `td` before them now?

Comment: The div has been removed from with the table and now sits just below it. I've changed the script to this 

$('td a').hover(function(){
$(this).find('div.productPopUp').fadeToggle();
});

Unfortunately, it still is not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
$('td a').hover(function(){
  $(this).parent().sibling('div.productPopUp').show();
});
```